# implement "\\ " instead of " " (space)

Tags: c, string, str-replace

i want to replace "\ " for every space when copying a string in C. 
This is needed for call function system(), it identifies spaces as "\ ".
So every space should be replace by that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *my_strcopy(char *destination,char *source){
char *p;
p=destination;

while(*source != '\0'){
    if(*source == ' '){
        *p='\\';
        *p++='\\';
        *p++='\\';
        *p++=' ';
    }
    else{
        *p=*source;
    }
    *p++;
    *source++;
    }
    *p='\0';
    return destination;
}
```

The output of this come as "hello\ �world\ �hi"
how to get the it correctly. need help

Comment: `*source++;` --> `source++;` and same with `p`

Comment: No need to double-escape the`\` for characters.

Comment: Your code replaces each space with two backslashes and a space (one backslash is copied over another, as well).

Comment: space should replace like "\\ ", when i typed \\, its not showing in the question also.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are adding too many `\` for each space when your requirement is to only have one. You were also incrementing the destination pointer more often than necessary. Finally, it is not necessary to deference the pointers at the bottom of the loop while incrementing them, although it does not hurt.

The following correction seems to produce the output you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *my_strcopy(char *destination,char *source){
    char *p;
    p=destination;

    while(*source != '\0'){
        if(*source == ' '){
            *p++='\\';
            *p=' ';
        }
        else{
            *p=*source;
        }
        p++;
        source++;
    }
    *p='\0';
    return destination;
}

int main(){
    char* src = "foobar bar bar";
    char dst[2048];
    my_strcopy(dst, src);
    printf("%s\n", dst);
}
```

Output:

```
foobar\ bar\ bar
```

Comment: `*p++;` and `*source++;` ??

Comment: @WeatherVane, Fixed. My original version minimized the Hamming distance from the OP's original code. :P

Comment: @JohnBollinger I mistook it for `(*p)++;`

Comment: @WeatherVane, understood.  I had to check a precedence table, myself.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly then the function can look like

```
char * my_strcopy( char *destination, const char *source )
{
    char *p = destination;

    do
    {
        if ( *source == ' ' ) *p++ = '\\';
        *p++ = *source;
    } while ( *source++ );

    return destination;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * my_strcopy( char *destination, const char *source )
{
    char *p = destination;

    do
    {
        if ( *source == ' ' ) *p++ = '\\';
        *p++ = *source;
    } while ( *source++ );

    return destination;
}

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "Hello world hi";
    char d[sizeof( s ) + 2];

    puts( s );
    puts( my_strcopy( d, s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs is

```
Hello world hi
Hello\ world\ hi
```

I hope the function does not contain any redundant code.:) The body of the function loop contains only two statements.:)

Comment: space should replace like "\\ ", when i typed \\, its not showing in the question also

Comment: @Deshan Kalupahana  No problem. Simply change this statement if ( *source == ' ' ) *p++ = '\\'; to if ( *source == ' ' ) *p++ = '\\', *p++ = '\\'; Only in my example you have to enlarge the destination array that to accomodate two additional characters.